# SimpleMDE\EasyMDE render custom code outside pre code

Tags: javascript, simplemde

I use EasyMDE (a fork of SimpleMDE) to display a Markdown editor on a web page. I like to add some custom controls and related HTML renders. For example, I like to add a callout like

[image]

So, I added this code

```
const easyMDE = new EasyMDE({
    element: document.getElementById(elementId),
    hideIcons: options.hideIcons,
    showIcons: options.showIcons,
    renderingConfig: {
        singleLineBreaks: false,
        codeSyntaxHighlighting: false,
        markedOptions: {
            langPrefix: "",
            highlight: function (code, lang) {
                if (lang === "mermaid" && mermaidInstalled) {
                    return mermaid.mermaidAPI.render('mermaid0', code, undefined);
                }
                else if (lang === "code" && hljsInstalled) {
                    const language = hljs.getLanguage(lang) ? lang : 'plaintext';
                    return hljs.highlight(code, { language }).value;
                }
                else if (lang === "tip") {
                    return '<div class="alert callout tip"><p class="title">' +
                        '<span class="icon icon-tip"></span></p><p>' +
                        code + '</p></div>';
                }
                else
                    return code;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The render is quite similar to what I expected but the

[image]

because the HTML for this code is contained in a `pre` and `code` tags

```css
pre {
  display: block;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  color: #212529;
}

pre {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

pre code {
  font-size: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  word-break: normal;
}

.alert.callout.tip {
  border-left-color: #28a745 !important;
}

.alert.callout {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-left-width: .25rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  background: var(--background);
}

.alert {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}

.alert.callout.tip .title {
  color: #28a745;
}

.alert .title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
}

.alert.callout.tip .icon-tip {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg width='1em' height='1em' viewBox='0 0 352 512' fill='%2328a745' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M96.06 454.35c.01 6.29 1.87 12.45 5.36 17.69l17.09 25.69a31.99 31.99 0 0026.64 14.28h61.71a31.99 31.99 0 0026.64-14.28l17.09-25.69a31.989 31.989 0 005.36-17.69l.04-38.35H96.01l.05 38.35zM0 176c0 44.37 16.45 84.85 43.56 115.78 16.52 18.85 42.36 58.23 52.21 91.45.04.26.07.52.11.78h160.24c.04-.26.07-.51.11-.78 9.85-33.22 35.69-72.6 52.21-91.45C335.55 260.85 352 220.37 352 176 352 78.61 272.91-.3 175.45 0 73.44.31 0 82.97 0 176zm176-80c-44.11 0-80 35.89-80 80 0 8.84-7.16 16-16 16s-16-7.16-16-16c0-61.76 50.24-112 112-112 8.84 0 16 7.16 16 16s-7.16 16-16 16z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E);
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code class="tip">
       <div class="alert callout tip">
          <p class="title"><span class="icon icon-tip"></span></p>
          <p>This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. This is a test for tips. </p>
       </div>
    </code>
</pre>
```

How can I limit the alert to be maximum width like the free space on the page and the words in the new line? Or remove the `pre` and `code` tags from the render?